# google drive sdk enterprise domain configuration

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to perform Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation of Authority via an in-house App Engine app (Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation). Does anyone know if this will be possible if the CPanel Setting 'Allow users to install Google Drive apps' is unchecked? Thanks!